# What actually happens internally

Tags: c#

I have these three linse in code

```
int i = 5;
object a = i;
i += 1;
```

I was thinking value of a will also be 6, but it is 5.

What happens actually please clear it

Comment: What does the documentation not answer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is What makes you think he knows anything about boxing?

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
object a = i;
```

the integer `i` is "boxed" (see also [Boxing and Unboxing (C# reference guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)), and a COPY of `i` is put into the box. Therefore changing the original `i` will have no effect on `a`, which is why you are seeing it unchanged when you inspect it.

Answer (score 2):

Value types are copies.

> Variables that are based on value types directly contain values.
>   **Assigning one value type variable to another copies the contained
>   value**. This differs from the assignment of reference type variables,
>   which copies a reference to the object but not the object itself.

[**Value Types** (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How exactly the assignment operator works depends on whether or not the you're copying a **value** or a **reference** type.  Basic types and structs, like int, are value types, while objects are reference types.

When you do:

```
int i = 5;
object a = i;
i += 1;
```

You copy the value of 5 to the stack and label it i.  Then, object a is created on the heap, and reference to it is placed on the stack, and the value of i is copied to object a.  Then, the i is incremented by one - the contents of object a on the heap haven't changed.

Here's a different example that might make the difference clearer:

```
class test{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Value i = new Value(5);
            Value a = i;
            i.number += 1;
            Console.WriteLine(i.number);
            Console.WriteLine(a.number);
        }
 }
 public class Value
 {
        public Value(int x){number = x;}
        public int number { set; get; }
 }
```

Both objects in this example will print 6 as the value of number, because a is now a reference to i.  If you're not sure if an object is a reference to another, you can always use the ReferenceEquals() method.